# How to access docker container behind traefik in home network

Tags: docker, traefik

I run a docker host in my homelab using ubuntu. The host is reachable via docker.mydomain.com. This is managed by my pfsense firewall.

I use the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.9"
    container_name: "traefik"
    hostname: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8008:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro"
  
  apache:
    image: httpd:latest
    container_name: apache
    hostname: apache
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache.rule=Host(`apache.docker.mydomain.com`)"
```

Additionally i use the following traefik.yml file

```
log:
  level: INFO

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
```

I can reach the traefik web ui but not the apache default site using apache.docker.mydomain.com. I'm not sure if pfsense is the problem or traefik. What am i missing here?

UPDATE:
I see the apache service in the traefik ui:

[image]

Comment: can you "see" the apache service in the traefik web ui? it might be helpfull to post screenshots of the traefik web ui (services, routers etc.) to get a sensee of what's going on and what traefik already services by your configuration. that is, if the documentation https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/overview/ does not get you any further

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the dns forwarding on the pfsense firewall. I added a wildcard rule to address=/.docker.mydomain.com/192.168.1.10 and now the apache is reachable via apache.docker.mydomain.com